# iphone - UITableView insert sections animation

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, animation

I have made a UITableView with 5 sections at first, 3 rows for each section. The first row is title, the second row is image, the third row is footer, and data is from internet, contains title, image, footer for each unit. Because the data is large, so I make paging to go next page by dragging the bottom of UITableView up, and go previous page by dragging the top of UITableView down. It's working like 9GAG Reader. I also want to make the same animation to 9GAG Reader while changing page, the animation is that -

.when the next page is ready, it will scroll to the next page  I did it, works fine.
.when the next page is done, the previous page will be deleted.

For each page, there are 5 sections, so I did it like this - I add 5 sections at page first, and if go next page, will add 5 more sections, and then scroll to the 5th section, so the scrolling animation is working well.

But for the next part, after I deleted 0-4 sections, the rest sections position is changed, that's a problem. I want the postion of the next page fixed, how can i make it?

```
// here expend to 2 page, 10 sections, and then scroll to the next page
self.totalSections = TOTAL_SECTIONS * 2;       
[self.mainContent reloadData];
[self.mainContent scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:TOTAL_SECTIONS] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];

// here delete the 0-5 sections, the previous page, but postion is changed..
NSIndexSet *deletes = [NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndexesInRange:NSMakeRange(0, 5)];
self.totalSections = TOTAL_SECTIONS;
[self.mainContent deleteSections:deletes withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am one of the two developer of 9Gag Reader, I'm not the one who did this part but I know how it works.
I think that the way you do it is a little bit too complex. To create the effect you are searching to recreate, we take a screenshot of the tableview and use it to do the effect which allows us not to add/delete rows which can lead to crashes, we just reload the content.

I hope it helps and it's not for a 9Gag Reader clone :p ! Tell us when your app is live (check the contact address on the itunes page) ;)

Regards,

Arthur @Appinest

Comment: Thank you for your great advices, definitely it's not 9Gag Reader clone, I borrowed (do you allow me to do so? :) some idea from your great app, and it's for a Chinese Comic site, only Chinese!

Comment: I got what you guys did, smart! :)

Comment: If the app is live, I will contact with u, actually I already did the first version by own design, but the client think its not fancy, and recommend me to reference to yours, I just changed it to the second version, all ideas borrowed mainly from yours. :)

Comment: If we allow you to borrow some of our ideas ? ARE YOU KIDDING ?! Of course, we are really proud about this :p And we did the same with other apps. Keep up the good work ;)

Comment: I will make an ios memecenter reader soon, check android version I did - https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jiayuan90.memereader. Thanks for your guys good work, learned a lot.

Answer (score -2):

I fixed the problem, seems this sequence is really cool -

```
self.totalSections = TOTAL_SECTIONS * 2;       
[self.mainContent reloadData];

[self prepareCellCacheTitle:0];

NSIndexSet *deletes = [NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndexesInRange:NSMakeRange(0, 5)];

self.totalSections = TOTAL_SECTIONS;

[self.mainContent deleteSections:deletes withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];

[self.mainContent reloadData];

[self.mainContent scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
```

Comment: reloadData = reloads everything from scratch. redisplays visible rows. So I don't see any interest to deal with deleteSections and your solution